# Create nodes from List<XElement> using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to create the following the xml

```
<BookStore>
  <Book>
    <Name></Name>
    <Author></Author>
    <Price></Price>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Name></Name>
    <Author></Author>
    <Price></Price>
  </Book>
</BookStore>
```

From

```
List<XElement> Book= xdoc.XPathSelectElements("s0:Name| s0:Author| s0:Price", namespaceManager).ToList();
```

I am struck in the following place :

```
XNamespace s0 = "urn:service.Bookstore.com";
XElement root=new XElement(s0 + "BookStore",
                 new XElement("Book",Book,
                              );
XDocument result = new XDocument(root);
```

But this gives the xml structure to be

```
<BookStore>
  <Book>
    <Name></Name>
    <Author></Author>
    <Price></Price>
    <Name></Name>
    <Author></Author>
    <Price></Price>
  </Book>
</BookStore>
```

Please help me in getting the expected output.Since the base xml structure looks like this

```
<BookStore>
  <Book>
    <Name></Name>
    <Author></Author>
    <Price></Price>
    <Name></Name>
    <Author></Author>
    <Price></Price>
  </Book>
</BookStore>
```

But I want it as two separate instances of

Comment: The code you've shown only creates a single `Book` element, and we've no idea where the `Book` variable comes from. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet : Updated. I am fetching these nodes from base xml using xpath select Element

Comment: Well we don't know what this "base XML" is which makes it hard to help you, too. How are you meant to work out which Name goes with which Author etc?

Comment: @JonSkeet : Included part of base xml

Comment: So what would you want to do if you had `<Name></Name><Name></Name><Author></Author>`?

Comment: In base xml, its know that Name,Author,Price is the order since the same is maintained in mainframe.

Comment: Right. So really, the problem is converting that ordered list of elements into *groups* of elements.

Comment: Ya I want to write it with enclosed <Book> tag

Comment: Right. I suspect you want GroupBy, but I can't help for another two hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you basically need to take the list of elements and group them into groups of 3 elements, putting each group in a `Book` element:

```
// The name/author/price elements you're already getting
var elements = ...; 
var groups = elements.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                     .GroupBy(pair => pair.index / 3, pair => pair.value);
XNamespace s0 = "urn:service.Bookstore.com";
XDocument result = new XDocument(new XElement(s0 + "BookStore",
    groups.Select(g => new XElement("Book", g))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try It:

```
XElement xElement = new XElement("BookStore", new XElement("Book", new XElement("Name", "value"), new XElement("Author", "value"), new XElement("Price", "value")));

xElement.Save("Location.xml");
```

Comment: No This gives me only one occurnce of <Book>

Comment: . What You Really Need?

Comment: <BookStore>
  <Book>
    <Name></Name>
    <Author></Author>
    <Price></Price>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Name></Name>
    <Author></Author>
    <Price></Price>
  </Book>
</BookStore> from List<Xelement> of Book

Comment: . Firts i Need Know How Your Code Work, Where This List Come Frok And After It i Can Make It For U... But Like Im Seeing, i Cant Help, Because i Cant Understand Your Code...